# cURL SSL Certificate error "Bad Certificate"

Tags: php, curl, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to send an SSL certificate with a soap message to a server and have only just managed to make cURL accept the certificate (.pem file spit out by putting a .pfx file through OpenSSL) and not return "unable to set private key file" (evidently the private key must keep its 'bag attributes'), however it's now returning exciting new errors:

> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I've tried setting the CA certificate with:

```
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caFile);
```

But this yields no results with the root nor the intermediate ca files I have.

Disabling this check with:

```
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

brings me to the new problem:

> error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate

This has been a thorn in my side for weeks now and while new error messages mean changes I'm not sure it means progress. Any advice or suggestions as to what is missing/I am doing wrong would be greatly appreiciated.

Comment: Turning off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is a bad idea - it allows man in the middle (MITM) attacks!

Comment: I'll need to keep them both on eventually. I'm just trying to get an understanding of SSL certificate use.

Our actual deployment won't even be in PHP but I find it has the most useful error messages...

Comment: SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed means that the client does not trust the CA signing the server certificate. SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate means that the server does not trust the CA signing the client certificate you are sending to him. How is the client certificate generated? Do you expect the server to trust the CA signing this certificate?

Comment: Are certificates signed against CAs on every request? If so my understanding is off.

I would expect the server to trust the CA. They are the folks who supplied the certificate files (the SSL authentication is so we can use their API).

Answer (score 1):

most likely the CA bundle is wrongful. verify the path & access permissions, maybe try setting an absolute path. if this not helps, get a [CA bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and set it alike `curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CAINFO,'cacert.pem');`

Answer (score -1):

`sslv3 alert bad certificate` means that CA information is missing. Use `--cacert` parameter and add CA cert.

`unable to set private key file` means that certificate passed as `--cert` is not the public key matched to private key